# Mikrotik dst-nat timeout

Tags: port-forwarding, mikrotik

I have installed a brand new Mikrotik RB2011UiAS-2HnD-IN in our Office.
Everything is working except port forwarding :(
I have disabled all other rules and filters but nothing helped .
I am able to ping the client from Mikrotik .
When I am trying to connect the port from out of office I see the that Statistics of dst-nat rule changes packets and bytes , but after few seconds it timed outs

```
/ip firewall nat
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat dst-port=3389 in-interface=pppoe-out1 \
    protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.1.101 to-ports=3389
```

Is there anything other that I have to check ?

Comment: do you have masquerading/src-nat going back from 192.168.1.101?

Comment: Also, does the windows box allow RDP connections from outside your lan? Can you see any packets arriving on the windows box (with wireshark for example) ? By default windows firewall does not allow RDP except for local connections.

Answer (score 2):

As damolp said you need to add a masquerade to go outside your network.

Run this:

```
/ip firewall nat add chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface=pppoe-out1
```